# Can you do custom routing for cms page?

Tags: url-rewrite, redirect, cms-pages, redirect-url

Can you change the url from cms page to a custom url? Is that something we could do with routes and show the cms page content

Comment: For which cms page you want to do and which custom URL you want to set?

Comment: @ZealousWeb anything example if I have url like about/company I want to redirect to custom route and set the url to be company/history

Comment: I have few other pages to change so I wasn’t able to set a custom route because all url are different